# GPU Is Underperforming When Connected Through An External Docking Station

Tags: gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, docking-station

I am using an external docking station to connect a desktop-based GPU `Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB` into my notebook `Lenovo ideapad 310`. After connecting it successfully and installing recommended drivers, I did a benchmark through this [userbenchmark tool](https://www.userbenchmark.com/) where i got a performance way below expectations, [check it here](https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/16983666). Any thoughts about what might be causing this issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the docking station connected? What model is it?

Comment: I am using NGFF/M.2

Answer (score 0):

the gpu i am using turned to be fake one,thank you.